# Are there two different huntling courier skins?

Tags: dota-2

Right now, you can see listings for the huntling: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Huntling

There seems to be two different images that associate with it right now.

[image: Yellowish Huntling] [image: Skin tone Huntling]

Everything I've seen so far indicates that there is only one model that resembles the last image. **It begs the question if there really is an alternate skin? Also, why Valve would have two different images for this courier, especially in the case of only one skin?**

I'd really prefer the first image if it does come in that variety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not a skin but a golden version of the normal courier which is hard to find. If you buy those 2 treasures (Imbued Trove Carafe 2015 and Lockless Luckvase 2015) then you will get a chance to get these both courier (venom and bounty) and if you are lucky then you will get a chance to get golden version of these courier or any golden version of other immortals.

- [Normal huntling](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Huntling)
- [Golden huntling](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Golden_Huntling)

The other courier:

- [Normal Venoling](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Venoling)
- [Golden Venoling](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Golden_Venoling)

You can also read this link for [more detail](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/105_-_Golden_Trove_Carafe_2015).

Comment: Yeah, I bought 5, and didn't get it either. :/

Comment: well i have bought 7 and even did not get any rare :( but last i used to get rare  but my luck..:(

Answer (score 0):

I bought one after waiting on it, and it turns out that it is only the one skin for sure, sadly.

Comment: While correct, your answer provides no additional content to what has already been posted. Perhaps you should post this as a comment?

Comment: @howdareyou, it is not that it does not answer the question, but OP is commenting on a previous answer, and only answers the question with the exact same answer. The second comment was the auto-comment for flagging the answer for deletion. Flagging answers does not allow custom messages, but as per [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/how-do-we-handle-duplicate-answers), duplicate answers should still be flagged for deletion. I interpret the content as "yes, the above answer is valid. I confirmed this, and am not happy with it"

Comment: @Timelord64 I agree that this is not exactly new information compared to the other answer. However, his answer was more of an "it is this way" statement. I was just adding to the fact by saying "It is this way, because I know it from first hand experience". I can definitely delete if you think I should, but I'm just clarifying why.

Comment: I understand what you've said to already be stated in the other answer. OP states that the purchase gives you the one skin. That said, if you do not believe it to be the same information, you should not delete it based off my opinion, alone. It is still good to see new users trying to add new information, and I could equally be incorrect. If your unsure, just leave it up to the votes, but don't feel bad if it is removed. It appears debatable - its come up again on the review queue. Rest assured everybody makes mistakes, and single instances do not reflect on the ability of the poster.

Comment: @Timelord64 Fair enough, I appreciate the input.